# In PHP, does the strength of session values have any effect on security?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

I'm just wandering if these two are identical in the sense of security.

```
if($submit){
 $_SESSION['user'] = true; 
}
```

vs

```
if($submit){
 $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = md5(uniquid()) . md5($email); 
}
```

One has simple key/value, the other slightly more obscure. But since sessions are stored in the server, are those similar or is the later more 'secure'?

Comment: ........No.....

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. Just curious..  What if they were cookies?

Comment: cookie are stored on the browser and therefore transmitted over the wire. So there it would make a difference

Comment: Generally speaking, cookies take care of security for you. If you want any extra security (ex: prevent cookie hijacking) you can store client's IP address and browser header information. If ip address or header changes, destroy session.

Comment: @Dimi hmm, that makes sense. Exception you want to say 'destroy cookie' at the end?

Comment: @user7342807 after comparing header/IP just do session_destroy();. It will user's cookie invalid (will also logout original user). Generally speaking, it makes user experience suck'ish, especially if they are on moble. But if you are building internal work only system, you can get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `$_SESSION` are in most cases obfuscated to your end users, and therefore do not need secrecy requirements.

If your threat model includes this information leaking out, you'll want to use something more secure than `md5()` and `uniqid()` to generate it. I recommend `random_bytes()` and `hash('sha384', $input)`.

Otherwise, you're fine just storing user IDs in `$_SESSION` and calling it a day.